# Azure Function: .NET Core: HTTP Trigger: Easy Auth: Get object id of identity

Tags: authentication, azure-functions, objectid

I have an Azure Function with HTTP Trigger using .NET Core 3.1 running on Windows with Premium Plan and Easy Auth enabled.

How can I retrieve the Object Id of the identity making the request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There two ways that work for Windows as well as Linux:

1. Via the request header `X-MS-CLIENT-PRINCIPAL-ID`
2. Via the ClaimsPrincipal

Example:

```
namespace FunctionApp1
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log,
            ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            string name = req.Query["name"];

            string objectIdHeaders = req.Headers["X-MS-CLIENT-PRINCIPAL-ID"];
            log.LogInformation($"Headers: {objectIdHeaders}");

            string objectIdClaims = claimsPrincipal.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier").Value;
            log.LogInformation($"Headers: {objectIdClaims}");

            string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
            dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
            name = name ?? data?.name;

            string responseMessage = string.IsNullOrEmpty(name)
                ? "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response."
                : $"Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.";

            return new OkObjectResult(responseMessage);
        }
    }
}
```